# Real Time data on web application

Tags: ajax, web-services, grails, web-applications, real-time-data

1. I have C++ Backend process run on A server. Any process can connect to A server to get real time data feed.
2. I have web application (grails) run on B server.
3. Client Access via web browser to http://bserver/

I have a feature that web client can monitor realtime data of A server
which client not be able to access A server directly due to firewall policy, but Web application on B server will connect (tcp socket) to A server and pass data to web client.

Would you mind to advise the way that easy to implement.

Comment: Browser -> Web sockets to Server B -> Spring Integration channel(s) to Server A ... That's one of the many ways you could do this. ... Of course Server A -> TCP to Server B Spring Integration Gateway -> Message Pipeline to Web socket channel -> Client Browser

Comment: @Joshua Moore Thank you